# How to call MS Graph via sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint with a large access token?

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, microsoft-graph-api, azure-sql-database

I'm using sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint in T-SQL to call Microsoft Graph endpoints. This is one of the use cases that Microsoft advertises. The headers parameter of sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint is an nvarchar(4000) so you are limited to 4000 characters. How do you call MS Graph when you have an access token that is larger than that?

I've implemented sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint in two different environments and in one of them the access token was short enough (around 3400 characters) to fit but in the other it's over 4000 characters.

Comment: This feature is still a preview feature so I guess just make sure you feedback to Microsoft if this is inadequate for advertised use cases and should be `nvarchar(max)`

Comment: Can't you create credentials and then use them instead of raw headers, as in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-invoke-external-rest-endpoint-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current&tabs=request-headers#credentials

Comment: Good point about feedback, @MartinSmith. Thanks!

Comment: Great point about credentials, @siggemannen. I've been using credentials for other APIs with static keys but didn't think to use them here since the Graph access token changes. I'll give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like credentials are not the solution. The SECRET of the credential is also limited to 4000 characters (although the documentation doesn't mention it). 

I think the real answer may be to use a managed identity, which I detest but...

Comment: Strange, it seems like a big oversight. But are you sure you're supposed to have a 4k+ token to use? It does sounds a bit unwidely. Can't you login with some other means?

Comment: Graph uses OAuth access tokens. I don't think I have any control of their length. And I'm using the same code, in different environments, to get the access tokens. I'm not sure why in one environment they are over 4000 and in the other environment they aren't.

Comment: And for anyone interested... using managed identity seems to be a dead end right now. I just get Audience errors. Microsoft mentions that access to Graph is allowed but they haven't given a sample for it yet (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-sql-db-invoke-external-rest-endpoints) so I wonder if they're still fine tuning things.

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary answer until sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint is improved or someone discovers something new.

sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint headers are limited to 4000 characters. Scoped credential secrets are also limited to 4000 characters. So you can't use either if your access token is greater than 4000 characters.

User managed identities don't seem to work either. You just get audience/scope errors.

So until Microsoft increases the limit on the size of the headers and the secrets, or explains how to get managed identities to work here, one solution is to ruthlessly trim down the permissions you've granted to whatever you're using to get the access token. (Probably an AD application) I was able to trim my access token by over 1000 characters by removing unnecessary permissions. Once you make the change, wait about 5 or 10 minutes for it to propagate and take full effect.